# Nutch and Elasticsearch Integration

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch

I'd like to know which versions of Nutch and Elasticsearch work well together to create a vertical search application (on AWS)?

If I plan on starting with 500 sites to crawl and increase from there, what are the best versions to use together.

I have Nutch 1.10 and ES 1.5 working together on my local machine for dev and testing purposes but I know as my data gets bigger (more sites crawled) this won't be feasible.

I'd like to use AWS EMR and store the crawled data on S3.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after much searching, reading and watching some videos... its pretty clear that Nutch 2.x (2.3) is a good choice. It seems to be better suited going forward and will work with ES.

-HTH anyone else facing similar situation